# mysql error 2026 RHEL 6

Tags: mysql, ssl, rhel6

I upgraded mysql to **5.7.21** on **RHEL6**. I created my self-signed certificates and added correct path in **my.cnf**, however, now I am getting **ERROR 2026** when trying to connect normally. I can connect only when I explicitly specify **SSL_DISABLED**. 
I have **double checked for RSA** appearing in key files. Relevant files are:

```
[root@my-DB1 log]# mysql -u myuser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't                                                                                         support it
```

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
#localhost
#sql_mod="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
ssl_capath=/var/lib/mysql/
ssl-cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:SEED-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:IDEA-CBC-SHA:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:KRB5-IDEA-CBC-SHA:KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:KRB5-IDEA-CBC-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC3-MD5:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:PSK-RC4-SHA:KRB5-RC4-SHA:KRB5-RC4-MD5

[client]
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql55-mysqld.log
pid-file=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**/var/log/mysql directory** contents:

```
[root@my-DB1 log]# ls /var/lib/mysql
auto.cnf    client-cert.pem  ibdata1      ibtmp1       logs.000003  logs.index  mysql.sock.lock     public_key.pem   my_db
ca-key.pem  client-key.pem   ib_logfile0  logs.000001  logs.000004  mysql       performance_schema  server-cert.pem  
ca.pem      ib_buffer_pool   ib_logfile1  logs.000002  logs.000005  mysql.sock  private_key.pem     server-key.pem
```

Any idea where am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea any one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-generated certificates with keeping in mind that the CN should be different for all 3.
Changed ownership on newly generated certificates to match mysql:mysql . 
Restarted mysql and this error is out.

Thanks